# Proof verification of property of row-reduced matrices based on observation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Suppose that $B$ is an $m\times n$ matrix in reduced row-echelon form. Build a new, likely
> smaller, $k\times l$ matrix $C$ as follows. Keep any collection of $k$ adjacent rows, $k\leq m$. From
> these rows, keep columns 1 through $l$,  $l\leq n$. Prove that C is in reduced row-echelon form.

By nature of the reduced row-echelon form, every leading 1 of a pivot column will appear to the right of the leading 1 in any row above it. So by selecting any $k$ adjacent rows, this property of the positioning of leading 1's will carry from matrix B to C $^{[1]}$.

A pivot column is a column where all entries are 0 except for one entry which is the leading 1 of a non-zero row. So in reduced row-echelon form, along with the fact of the nature of the "cascading 1's", the entries of a matrix "below and to the left of" all leading 1's are guaranteed to be zero$^{[2]}$. So in choosing columns 1 through $l$ in any $k$ adjacent rows, all zero-rows appear at the bottom of matrix C, below any non-zero rows.

These 2 properties together show that C is in reduced row echelon form.

$[1]$ - I dont know how to formally prove this. This is just what I can see from looking at a few examples but I can't justify it step-by-step.

$[2]$ - Same problem as in $[1]$: Looking at examples I can see the bottom-left hand corner of row reduced matrices being all 0. I take this for granted but is that ok?

For the record, I am self-studying Linear Algebra. This is not included in the solutions manual and the only computational tool I have at this point is Gaussian-Elimination.

> Can I take for granted observation-based results here?